# Improving the accuracy of model in R

Tags: r, svm, r-caret, nnet

I have the following dataset . The outcome variable is State which is of 3 types.The variables and sample data are as follows:

```
 No.    Var2    Var3    Var4    Var5    Var6    Var7           Var8   Var9    Var10  Var11  State
297 middle a    NA       NA     16  working fu $25000 or more   more    1        1     NA     P
299 middle a    NA       no     9   working fu  $25000 or more  sevrl   NA       1     0      N
300 middle a    no       NA     12  working fu  $25000 or more  every   4        1     0      P
301 foreign     NA       no     17  working fu  $25000 or more  never   NA       0     0      P
303 middle a    no       no     19  working fu  NA             every   1        0     NA     P
304 middle a    no       NA     17  retired     $25000 or more  every   2        1     0      P
305 foreign     no       no     17  working fu  $25000 or more  sevrl   1        1     NA     P
306 middle a    no       no     16  working fu  $25000 or more  once    1        1     NA     V
```

The Outcome variable are of three classes P,N, V.

I have to predict the state for unknown data , by using this data.
I have divided the data and built models in R with one set and checked with the other.

Have tried the following model in R :

```
  library(caret)
  control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
  xgbGrid <-  expand.grid(max_depth  = c(1, 3, 5, 9),nrounds = (7:14)*100,eta = 0.1)
  ModelXGB <- train(Happy ~ ., data=MerTrain3, method="xgbTree",   trControl = control , tuneGrid = xgbGrid)
  predXGB <- predict(ModelXGB , newdata=MerTest3, type="raw")

# This gave me accuracy of 0.700297177
```

I want to improve the accuracy . Please suggest me any algorithm in R to improve the accuracy of this multiclass data. I have tried simple svm, nnet without any increase in accuracy.
Please also explain what fine tuning of parameters in the suggested model need to be done. I can share the data set, if any link is provided.
Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I have flagged to close. This is a primarily opinion-based question.

Comment: Agree not yet a specific coding question. Perhaps more on-topic if offered to a forum that handles statistical methods or "machine learning" questions where strategies for investigating residuals might be discussed.

Comment: Agreed. There are many, often controversial, opinions on this. A potential solution, however, would be to examine how various machine learning models affect the accuracy (logistic, svm, lda, ect) and make it more about examining how your data fits these models rather than how to make it more accurate.